# Restrict shape movement inside another shape in AutoCAD

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am creating plugin in AutoCAD for shape container, for this inner entity can only be move within the container, as per my basic knowledge to AutoCAD this can be done using JIG class.

Please suggest any code or sample to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a jig can be used for movement & placement.  Inside of the jig you can restrict the movement by looking at the point(s) acad passes into your jig code and the altering those point(s) to keep the in the jig inside your restricted area.

Your code will be responsible for detecting collision/crossing of the container and calculating an correction to the points being dragged.